# Android install apk Jelly Bean

Tags: android, apk

Добрый день.

Возникла следующая проблема при установки apk. При скачивании apk c сети в последствии не могу установить его именно на api 16-18. 
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Пишет ошибку "there was a problem parsing package".

В логах:

```
08-14 10:27:32.390 I/ActivityManager: START {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///data/data/ru.myapp.agent/files/myapp.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity u=0} from pid 21303

                                  --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
                                  [ 08-14 10:27:32.450  1405: 1435 D/         ]
                                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb86cc0e0, tid 1435
08-14 10:27:32.920 W/zipro: Unable to open zip '/data/data/ru.myapp.agent/files/myapp.apk': Permission denied
08-14 10:27:32.920 D/asset: failed to open Zip archive '/data/data/ru.myapp.agent/files/myapp.apk'
08-14 10:27:32.920 W/PackageInstaller: Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation
08-14 10:27:32.920 W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{af2e3258 ru.myapp.agent/agent.myapp.ru.mvp.activities.home.HomeActivity}
08-14 10:27:32.920 W/PackageParser: Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/data/ru.myapp.agent/files/myapp.apk
                                java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
```

Путь формируется следующим образом

```
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    String downloadedApkPath;
    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        File baseDirFile = appContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        if(baseDirFile == null) {
            downloadedApkPath = appContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            downloadedApkPath = baseDirFile.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    } else {
        downloadedApkPath = appContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    }
    downloadedApkPath += File.separator + "myapp.apk";
```

установка:

```
public void startInstallNewApk(String downloadPath) {
    File apkFile = new File(downloadPath);
    Intent intent;
    Uri uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", apkFile);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        uri = Uri.fromFile(apkFile);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    }
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут же все ясно написано:

> 08-14 10:27:32.920 W/zipro: Unable to open zip '/data/data/ru.myapp.agent/files/myapp.apk': Permission denied

Нет доступа к файлу.
Это приватная папка приложения, никто кроме этого приложения не имеет к ней доступа. И инсталлятор тоже.